# How to compute 3D rotation matrix by user movement of control point

Tags: user-interface, matrix, 3d

I have a projected view of a 3D scene. The 2D points are computed by multiplying the 3D points in homogenous coordinates by a view matrix (which includes a translation and rotation) and a perspective matrix. I want to allow the user to move control points which describe the three axes, and update the rotation matrix based on this.

How do I compute the new rotation matrix given a change in projected 2D coordinates, assuming rotation around the origin? Solving for the position of the end of the single axis has a large degeneracy in the set of possible, but maybe solving for rotation in the axes perpendicular to the moved axis might work.

Comment: You need at least 2 sample points to constrain the axis in 3D

Comment: One end of the axis is tied to the origin. Clearly it should be possible to calculate how to move the other end from point A to B  by rotation without rotating about that axis.